# How it is ordered if I query by secondary index?

Tags: cassandra, cql

I created this table on cassandra.

```
CREATE TABLE user_event(
    userId bigint,
    type varchar,
    createdAt timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY ((userId), createdAt)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (createdAt DESC);
CREATE INDEX user_event_type ON user_event(type);
```

If I query by userId query result will be ordered by createdAt column.

```
SELECT * FROM user_event WHERE userId = 1;
```

But how it is ordered if I query by type? Can I get last SIGN_IN event?

```
SELECT * FROM user_event WHERE userId = 1 AND type = 'SIGN_IN' LIMIT 1;
```

Is there any guarantee that result is ordered by createdAt?

Answer (score 1):

The key to understanding this scenario, is to remember that result set order can only be enforced *within* a partition.  As you are still querying by partition key (`userId`) all data within each partition will still be ordered by `createdAt` (DESCending).

"Guarantee" is a strong word, and one that I am hesitant to use.  The results queried in this way *should* maintain their on-disk sort order.  **I would definitely test it out.**  But as long as you provide `userId` as a part of the query, the results should be returned sorted by `createdAt`.